# case insensitive in cassandra while filtering the user email

Tags: python, cassandra, case-insensitive

Hello guys i have a query where I'm getting the user email from the web services where i want to filter the user email either it is(lower/upper case) provided by the user while login:

```
user = User.objects.filter(email_id=v1_api.payload['email_id']).first()
```

here "v1_api" is blueprint in flask-restplus this code work fine if the user enters the email address which is same as the database but its throws an exception when I write "CAPSLOCK@gmail.com" in place of "capslock@gmail.com" 
I want it to make case insensitive either the email in lower/uppper it should always considered it as a lower case...
In other database like SQLAlchemy we can do this in such a way:

```
from sqlalchemy import func
user = models.User.query.filter(func.lower(User.username) == func.lower("GaNyE")).first()
```

But in cassandra I'm not able to do it please suggest me how to do this .....thanks

Comment: If you're feeding it in from python, why don't you just convert to lowercase in python and then insert it into your database?

Comment: @lordingtar its not about how i'm storing it to the database its about the how the user login sometime user writes the upercase email while doing login so that part i want to edit if the user email is total match only it is in upper case so for that i don't want to throw an error i just want to make the user login case insensitive

Comment: @lordingtar please tell me is there any way that we make the email to the lower case while filtering from db in cassandra

Comment: You have to make it lowercase before insertion or before checking. Cassandra does not provide a way to convert it at the point of entry

Comment: When you're reading in the user email, just use `email = method_to_get_email.lower()`

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do this in Cassandra - Cassandra queries by precise value that you provided, it couldn't apply any function during the query. So you need to do the "normalization" of email when you're inserting data into database.